# LINQ query for getting data from 3 tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am using SQL Server 2017, .Net 4.5 and EF core.

I have the following tables: Student_Course: has Student_Id, Course_ID and Student
_Course_ID - pk.

Student: First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Student_ID - PK
Course: Id pk, Name

I am trying to retrieve a list of students with their respective
courses. I also need the course count for each student.

For the above mentioned tables I have the following entities in C#
Student_Course: Has navigational properties for list of students and courses
Student:
Course:

I am trying to make this query using LINQ:

Controller:

```
public IList<StudentCourse> GetStudents()
{
Student_CourseContext scContext = new Student_CourseContext();
             
var studentCourses = (from sc in scContext.Student_Course
                      from student in sc.Students.Where( x => x.Student_ID == 
     sc.Student_ID) 
                      from course in sc.Courses.Where (x => x.ID == sc.Course_ID)
                      where sc.Student_ID == student.Student_ID
                      && sc.Course_ID == course.ID
                      && student.First_Name != "None"
                      //join course in sc.Courses
                     //from sc in studentCourseEntity.Student_Courses.GroupBy( x => x.Student_ID)
                     select new StudentCourse
                     {
                             StudentName = student.First_Name + ' ' + student.Last_Name,
                            //CourseCount = sc.Gr,
                            Course = string.Join(",", course.Name)
                     }).ToList();
    return studentCourses.ToList();
}



        }
```

It is returning a query like this:

```
SELECT ([s0].[First_Name] + CAST(N' ' AS nvarchar(max))) + [s0].[Last_Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Student_Course] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [Student] AS [s0] ON ([s].[Student_Course_ID] = [s0].[Student_Course_ID]) AND ([s].[Student_ID] = [s0].[Student_ID])
INNER JOIN [Course] AS [c] ON ([s].[Student_Course_ID] = [c].[Student_Course_ID]) AND ([s].[Course_ID] = [c].[ID])
WHERE (([s].[Student_ID] = [s0].[Student_ID]) AND ([s].[Course_ID] = [c].[ID])) AND (([s0].[First_Name] <> N'None') OR [s0].[First_Name] IS NULL)
```

Instead of joining on the columns pecfied it is joining on STudent_Course_ID which is the primary key of the Student_Course table. Due to this join I am getting the error:

> Invalid column name 'Student_Course_ID'. Invalid column name 'Student_Course_ID'.

since the Student and Course tables do not have this field. Please let
me know how I can make this work.

I tried mode.OnCreating method to define the relationship betweeen
these tables but I am able to map between Student, Student_Course and
Course tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Student_Course:     public class Student_Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int Student_Course_ID { get; set; }
        public int Student_ID { get; set; }
        public int Course_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Student> Students {get; set;}
        public virtual IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Student: public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Student_ID { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Student_Course> Student_Course { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Course:     public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Student_Course> Student_Courses { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Quote syntax in the question editor is for quoting other content, not your question. i.e. when you copy text from somewhere else. And when providing clarifying information, please [edit] directly into your question.

Comment: If your `Student_Course` class is an implementation of many-to-many relationship, then it'd better to have navigation properties for single student and user in this class. I don't understand why you have lists there.

Comment: Check your class / xsd of EF. Did something set wrong for table `Student` and `Student_Course`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the classes and mappings. Comments are hard to read. Also add navigation properties to you classes so you don't have to have these "joins" (`where sc.Student_ID == student.Student_ID` etc.). Once the navigation properties are correct you'll never have faulty joins.

Answer (score 1):

So you want for every Student his name and the list (collection?) of the names of all courses he attends.

```
var studentsWithTheCoursesTheyAttend = dbContext.Students
    .Select(student => new
    {
        Name = student.First_Name + ' ' + student.Last_Name,
        Courses = dbContext.Student_Course
            .Where(studentCourse => studentCourse.StudentId == student.Id)
            .Select(studentCourse => dbContext.Courses
                .Where(course => course.Id == studentCourse.CourseId)
                .Select(course => course.Name)
                .FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList(),                    
    }
```

Explanatation: from every Student in the complete table of Students, take his name:

```
... = dbContext.Students
    .Select(student => new
    {
        Name = student.First_Name + ' ' + student.Last_Name,
```

Also select all the Student_Courses of this Student (= all Student_Courses that have a foreign key StudentId that equals the primary key of the Student):

```
Courses = dbContext.Student_Course
    .Where(studentCourse => studentCourse.StudentId == student.Id)
```

From every selected Student_Course of this Student you want to get the Name of the Course that this Student_Course refers to. For this we will first get all Courses with a primary key equal to the foreign key StudentCourse.CourseId:

```
        .Select(studentCourse => dbContext.Courses
            .Where(course => course.Id == studentCourse.CourseId)
```

Well, we don't want the complet course, we only want its Name:

```
            .Select(course => course.Name)
```

Well, we know that every studentCourse will only have exactly one Course that it refers to, not zero, not more than one. After all, the foreign key `studentCourse.CourseId` refers to exactly one Course.

Therefore we only have to take the first one. I could have used `First()`, but some Providers in the IQueryable report problems when using First, hence I use `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
             .FirstOrDefault(),
```

So by now, from ever Student, I have his Name, and the Names of all Courses he attends. Make this a List of courses:

```
Courses = ...
    .ToList(),
```

So now you have something like this:

```
{
    Name = "Sukumar Krishnamurthy",
    Courses =
        {
            "Advanced .NET",
            "All aspects of LINQ",
            "Ups and downs of C#",
        },
},
{
    Name = "Harald Coppoolse",
    Courses =
        {
            "Windows Services",
            "REST in a proper manner",
        },
},
```

Property `Courses` is the List of Names of Courses that the Student attends. The length of the List represents the number of attended Courses.

If desired you can transform this list of Courses into one string with Names. However I am not sure that this will improve readability:

```
"Windows Services REST in a proper manner"
```